# Apply for an other visa while J2 application is on progress

Tags: usa, working-visas, h1-visa, j-visa

My wife and me are planning to go to the US. I'll have a J1 (postdoc) and she therefore get's a J2. At the moment she's looking for a job in Academia/Industry. In case she finds one, can she still apply for her own J1/H1B even though she started the application for a J2?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, she can. Keep in mind that J1 may have limitation on staying in the US (i.e.: you must stay out of the US for some period of time, typically 2 years, before coming back in any other status). This may affect you and her. Check your paperwork.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already know about the 2 Years go home policy which is fine by me. I'm sure you're right about your answer but do you have a source for it? Just that I have something I can lean on.

Comment: @magu_ it's hard to find a source for something that doesn't exist. There's no such limitation - so no source.